# Why won't MenubarCountdown stay on the Menubar after reboot

Tags: c++, osx-lion, menubar

I'm trying to get some help for a little GPL app.

I recently updated to Lion from 10.5. I had been using MenubarCountdown-1.2 which was accessible via the Menubar.

For some reason, it now vanishes from the Menubar when I reboot.

Here is the source:
http://capablehandstech.com/menubarcountdown

I was hoping there was a little Config file I could modify to update the app, but I've never worked with C++.